# SWIG from c to Python. Add custom method to generated py file

Tags: python, swig

I have SWIG from c to Python.
Is it possible to add custom method to generated py file using SWIG interface or have to change manually py file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the `%pythoncode` and related directives.

SWIG 3.0 documentation reference: [36.6.2 Adding additional Python code](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn42).